# domxpath- how to get content for parent tag only instead of child tags

Tags: dom, xpath

I, am using domxpath query for fetching content for parent tag only that is (td[class='s']) instead of including div content which is nested inside that td  as given below in my code.

```
<?php
$second_trim='<td class="s" style="line-height:18px;">THIS TEXT IS REQUIRED and <div id="a"         style="display:none;background-color:black;border:1px solid #ddd;padding:5px;color:black;">THIS TEXT     IS  NOT REQUIRED </div></td>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
@$dom->loadHTML($second_trim);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$b = $xpath->query('//td[@class="s"]');
    echo "<p style='font-size:14px;color:red;'><b style='font-size:18px;color:gray;'>cONTENT :-        </b>".$b->item(0)->nodeValue."</p>"; 
?>
```

so how to remove content of that div tag and fetching only td's content any ideas !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

If you are only interested in the direct text content modify your xpath query:

```
$b = $xpath->query('//td[@class="s"]/text()');
echo '<p style="font-size:14px;color:red;">'
        .'<b style="font-size:18px;color:gray;">cONTENT :-        </b>'
        .$b->item(0)->nodeValue
    .'</p>';
```

Right now the result is very specific to the example:
If more than one direct text node exists, its not gone be displayed. To do that `foreach` through the DOMNodeList `$b` and echo every selected node value.